# Error 500 when deploying Symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, deployment

I uploaded a symfony2 project to a FTP server. My app works fine on local but I get Error 500 when I try to access the web folder live. Same with web/app_dev.php/

-I cleared the cache
-checked if the DB paramaters match the live server
-created the database & tables
-gave 777 permission to logs and cache folder
-ran app/check.php, it says the system is ready to run symfony...

I don't know what to do .. I did a lot of googling but nothing helped

Comment: What does `app/log/prod_log` output?

Comment: Did you install the vendors in your new environnement ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I contracted the webhost support and they fixed the issue. Apparently permissions for the app.php file were wrong